# Running Java GUI applications through a Linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, bash, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu trying to run a Java GUI application through the terminal. I'm getting a HeadlessException when I try to run it. Below is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:437)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:419)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:384)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:174)
    at gui.ImageViewer.<init>(ImageViewer.java:34)
    at displayrunner.DisplayRunner$1.run(DisplayRunner.java:15)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:226)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:617)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

I tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before running the application, but that had no effect. How do you run a GUI application through Bash?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess you only have the `default-jre-headless` package installed. Check that you have `default-jre`.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Package was there with Ubuntu but not installed. "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre"

Comment: worked for me too. in my case i had only default-jdk-headless installed. so, I installed default-jdk

Comment: just a remark: in Fedora/RedHat distributions this package is called

'java-N.N.N-openjdk'

(where NNN is the version number)

Answer (score 7):

I had this exception. I tried setting the headless setting to false, and it worked for me:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Djava.awt.headless=false'
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but did cause it to provide a more helpful message (missing library)

Answer (score 3):

If you run your application on Ubuntu by the command:

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

then OpenJDK is used. Try to install the Sun JDK and run your application like:

```
/usr/java/jre1.6.0_22/bin/java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the command `update-java-alternatives` to select the default Java on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a GUI, you can't run it. Are you running remotely (for example, SSH)?

If so, look into the system that you're using for remote access. For example, with SSH you want to look at the `AllowX11Forwarding` setting [(SSH FAQ entry)](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.7).

Comment: I am not remote. I'm running Ubuntu on my laptop.

Comment: Then if you don't have a GUI running, you can't run a GUI app.

Comment: Ah, you're running this through a terminal in X?  In that case, you need to look at the terminal's instructions to ensure that the DISPLAY variable is being set properly.  Unfortunately, there are as many possibilities as there are different terminals.  Try using a basic terminal such as XTerm for troubleshooting.